# $create(Sys.Extended.UI.ResizableControlBehavior, ...) fails with error "Unable to get property 'UI' of undefined..." unless a control already exists

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

There seems to be 2 separate issues behind this error. One is using scriptmanager instead of toolkitscriptmanager. I'm using toolkitscriptmanager but I get this error if I try to $create a control/behavior without already having one on the page. If I have a control on the page, without changing anything else, there's no error.

I'm using using the .net4.0 version of AjaxControlToolkit.

works:

```
    <div id="divTest" style="height:500px; width:500px; background:#ccc">test</div>

    <script>
        Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
            $create(
                Sys.Extended.UI.ResizableControlBehavior,
                {
                    "ClientStateFieldID": "ResizableControlExtender1_ClientState",
                    "HandleCssClass": "handle",
                    "HandleOffsetX": 0,
                    "HandleOffsetY": 0,
                    "MaximumHeight": 800,
                    "MaximumWidth": 800,
                    "MinimumHeight": 220,
                    "MinimumWidth": 478,
                    "ResizableCssClass": "resizing",
                    "id": "ResizableControlBehavior1"
                }, null, null, $get("divTest"));
        });
    </script>

    <div id="divWrapper" runat="server"></div>
            <asp:ResizableControlExtender   ID="divWrapper_ResizableControlExtender" 
                                        runat="server" 
                                        TargetControlID="divWrapper" 
                                        HandleCssClass="handle" 
                                        ResizableCssClass="resizing" 
                                        MaximumHeight="800" 
                                        MaximumWidth="800" 
                                        MinimumHeight="220" 
                                        MinimumWidth="478"
                                        HandleOffsetX="0" 
                                        HandleOffsetY="0"></asp:ResizableControlExtender>
```

doesn't work:

```
    <div id="divTest" style="height:500px; width:500px; background:#ccc">test</div>

    <script>
        Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
            $create(
                Sys.Extended.UI.ResizableControlBehavior,
                {
                    "ClientStateFieldID": "ResizableControlExtender1_ClientState",
                    "HandleCssClass": "handle",
                    "HandleOffsetX": 0,
                    "HandleOffsetY": 0,
                    "MaximumHeight": 800,
                    "MaximumWidth": 800,
                    "MinimumHeight": 220,
                    "MinimumWidth": 478,
                    "ResizableCssClass": "resizing",
                    "id": "ResizableControlBehavior1"
                }, null, null, $get("divTest"));
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved!

All i needed to do was dig through the source of a working page and find this script tag and then copy it over to the broken version:

```
<script src="/myapp/mypage.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager1_HiddenField&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.7.607%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3afc974eef-02bb-4a84-98bd-02b839b496d1%3ade1feab2%3af9cec9bc%3a6beb6cd0" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm just kidding. I switched to jquery.